# How to clean cells using SAS regex

Tags: sas

I have a table

```
id Attribute                          Other
1  Written Jan 20 File: 78yt8fgkje    ....
2  12/22/2004 File: 3Bsdffsdf85       ....
3  12/17/2004 File: 5Osdfdsf58384     ....
4  Some May File: 0w98ejcj            ....
5  10/24/2001 File: 2Ddsfsdfd1429     ....
          ....................
```

I need to remove everything that goes **after** the `File:` word in the `Attribute` variable

How can I do this?

---

I tried this solution from internet. It does not work and I do not understand what is `32767`

```
data newDataSet;
set oldDataSet;
regex1 = prxparse("/ File:.*? /");
call  prxchange(rx1, 32767, Attribute);
run;
```

Comment: A standard RegExp (^.*?File:) -- ^ denotes the beginning of the text, .*? is a non-greedy find any character zero or more times, File: is just the end of the string you would like.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I want to get rid of the `File.......` part and leave whatever is preceding it. Could you correct my coding . Thank you

Comment: 32767 is the number of times to make the change.  It shows someone who didn't read the documentation well, as -1 will just match all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PRX is probably overkill for this.

```
data want;
set have;
filepos = find(attribute,'File:');
if filepos>0 then attribute=substr(Attribute,1,filepos+5);
run;
```

Filepos+5 is to keep "File:" as you say "after".  IF you want to get rid of "File:" as well, just get rid of the +5.

Comment: It runs but does not change anything ... It creates a new variable `filepos` which contains all `0` values

Comment: Try it now - I think I swapped the arguments to `find`.